# Can htaccess RewriteRule be used to send data, rather than a URL?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

For the fun value of it, can htaccess rewriteRule be used to return content, rather than a URL?

If I add the following to htaccess file

```
RewriteRule ^.*\.gif$ data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAD/ACwAAAAAAQABAAACADs%3D [R=200,L]
```

Apache treats it as a relative URL, and rewrites the result as

```
data://domain-name/image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAD/ACwAAAAAAQABAAACADs%3D
```

From a quick look at the source code, this behavior seems to be hard coded. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: I doubt this is possible just by means of a rewriting rule. You might be able to create an additional header though on protocol level. But the actual issue probably is what _clients_ make from that. As far as I can see there is nothing mentioned in this direction in the RFC passages describing the "Location" header. They all mention _references_ , relative or absolute and how clients have to interpret such references in combination with a given target. So I doubt this is worth playing around with.

Comment: @arkascha I'm not sure what clients would make from that. Pasting the data URL above into Chrome & Firefox address bar causes them to display a one pixel gif, so possibly they'd make something out of it.

Comment: Trying to do a `header('Location: data:image/gif;base64,...');` from within a PHP script only makes my Chromium-based browser respond with a "This site can’t be reached" error page, and `ERR_UNSAFE_REDIRECT`. So this is probably not worth pursuing further from the client-side perspective already.